# How to repeat a command when there's a specific string in a file?

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting

I want to repeat a command while there's a specific string in it's output, which indicates that there was an error.
The command is `gksu ./installer.run > ./inst.log 2>&1`
What I want do is to repeat it while there's `'string'` in `./inst.log`.
How can I do this from a bash command-line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find string in a file:

```
grep -q string file
```

The exit value tells you if grep found anything.

Then you can loop as long as a command returns a true exit value:

```
while command ; do
    repeat this
done
```

Though you want to run the command at least once, so maybe

```
while true ; do
    some command
    if ! grep -q string file ; then
        break         # jump out of the loop if it's _not_ there
    fi
done
```

Otherwise you'd need to repeat the command before the loop and inside it.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in `while while-cmd-list; do do-cmd-list; done`, `while-cmd-list` is *also* a list of commands. It doesn't have to be a single command.

So you can do:

```
while
  gksu ./installer.run > ./inst.log 2>&1
  grep -q string inst.log
do
  echo >&2 "Trying again, output contained string"
done
```

Though here, you could also do:

```
while
  gksu ./installer.run 2>&1 |
    tee ./inst.log |
    grep string > /dev/null
do
  echo >&2 "Trying again, output contained string"
done
```

(note that we're not using `-q`, as that would mean `grep` could exit early causing the installer to receive a SIGPIPE).